# Visual Studio "Convert to Web Application" and "Could not load type" errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm currently getting a "Could not load type UI.Administration.Site.master" error message and I'm not really sure as to why.

I have an ASP.NET MVC Project with the UI namespace.  Within the project's structure, I have an Admin folder.  I right clicked on the Admin folder and chose "Convert to Web Application", but am getting a Could Not Load Type error for my master page.

Are there any special things that must occur in these situations for this to work?

> **ERROR INFO BELOW**

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'UI.Administration.Site'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="UI.Administration.Site" %>

Comment: Did you build it? Also, please post the full error message.

Comment: Thanks. Did you build the application? Usually the reason for "could not load type" is that tye type does not exist in the binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had always wondered what this command did. I'm sure I've tried it and seen no result. I finally just looked it up:

"Convert to Web Application" has nothing to do with your scenario. It's for converting Visual Studio .NET and Visual Studio .NET 2003 to Visual Studio .NET 2008.

See "[Walkthrough: Converting a Visual Studio 2002 or 2003 Web Project to a Visual Studio 2008 Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907676.aspx)".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespaces match up with your folder structure as well as in your Inherits clause and your CodeBehind attributes.  I had the same problem and it was because the namespace in the Inherits attribute didn't match up when I converted.